# .htaccess block user to access some directory but using the file in that directory via jquery ajax

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory called "db_interface". In this directory there are all the files .php that allow me to retrieve data from my database. If someone try to search one of this file in the searchbar of chrome or firefox, he can access to all of this content. I've tried to put in this directory an .htaccess file with

deny from all

and it worked. But if I want to use this files to provide the login or to do some ajax call, I have the same 403 error handled by the .htaccess.

In a nutshell I want be able to use this file only if is another page to call them and not if is an user using chrome or firefox searchbar.

Thanks to all

Comment: The best you can do is: when rendering out your page doing the AJAX request, generate a Nonce (or cryptographically random string), store it in a database, and send this Nonce along with the AJAX request to  `/db_interface/whatever.php`. In this PHP file, verify the nonce - if wrong or not specified, output nothing.

This will however not guarantee this cannot be automated, but will at least prevent users from just accessing the URL (I mean, they can still fiddle out the Nonce from your page and use this, but it's at least a little harder).

Answer (score 0):

Update your .htaccess file in **db_interface** with following code.
It will prevent all the files from the direct access, but you can include all those prevented files in another independent file, and make d :

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```